# Form fields validation order

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, constraints

Here is entity bound to the form.

**validation.yml**

```
My\Bundle\Entity\User:
    properties:
        login:
            - NotBlank:
                message: "Login is empty."
            - Length:
                min: 3
                max: 16
            - My\Bundle\Validator\Constraints\Alphanumeric: ~
```

and here is one field not bound

**RegisterType.php**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('login', 'text', array('label' => 'Login'));
    ...
    $builder->add('captcha', 'captcha', array(
        'label'       => 'Captcha',
        'mapped'      => false,
        'constraints' => array(new ContainsCaptcha)
    ));
}
```

check for errors

**MyController.php**

```
$formFields = $form->all();
foreach ($formFields as $key => $field) {
    if ($field->getErrorsAsString()) {
        $errors = $field->getErrors();
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
            $messages[$key][] = $error->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
var_dump($messages);
```

Captcha is not validated like others.
It can have an error and *only one* from other fields can have an error.

I think it would be right to have two alternatives:

1/ get errors for all invalid fields at the same time (login, email, ..., captcha)

2/ do not validate captcha if login or other has already failed

How to do it?

Moreover login is always gets validated first. Changing declaration order in validation.yml or buildForm() doesn't change anything. I guess it depends on Entity.orm.yml declaration order. How to change this order w/o changing entity metadata.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
$user = new User();

$validator = $this->get('validator');
$errors = $validator->validate($user);

if (count($errors) > 0) {
    return new Response(print_r($errors, true));
} else {
    return new Response('The author is valid! Yes!');
}
```

Comment: I'm validation a form here, not a user directly

Answer (score 0):

I changed some validations, maybe it fixed something, but most certainly errors retrieval was flawed.
Got it fixed here - [Symfony2 repeated type does not validate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17927040/symfony2-repeated-type-does-not-validate)