# Symfony2 repeated type does not validate

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I have two password fields. That extra is for confirmation.
And there is no error message when both are empty or when passwords don't match.

How to enable or debug this validation which I presume should be working out of the box (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/repeated.html#validation)?

```
class MyType extends AbstractType
{
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'My\\Bundle\\Entity\\User',
        ));
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        ...
        $builder->add('password', 'repeated', array(
            'invalid_message' => 'Passwords must match.',
            'type'            => 'password',
            'required'        => true,
            'first_options'   => array('label' => 'Password'),
            'second_options'  => array('label' => 'Repeat Password')
        ));
```

**form.html.twig**

```
...
<form action="" method="post" novalidate>
...
<tr>
    <td>{{ form_label(regForm.password.first) }}</td>
    <td>{{ form_widget(regForm.password.first, { 'attr': {'pattern': '.{6,}','title': 'Minimum 6 characters long'} } ) }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form_label(regForm.password.second) }}</td>
    <td>{{ form_widget(regForm.password.second, { 'attr': {'pattern': '.{6,}', 'title': 'Minimum 6 characters long', 'data-equals': '#register_password_first'} } ) }}</td>
</tr>
```

Validators declared in **validation.yml** seem to have no effect on the issue.

```
My\Bundle\Entity\User:
    properties:
        ...
        password:
            # this one does not work because of "repeated" type in buildForm()???
                - NotBlank:
                    message: "Password is required."
                - MinLength:
                    limit: 6
                    message: "Password must have at least {{ limit }} characters."
```

**Controller.php** (original version)

```
...
if (!$form->isValid()) {
    $formFields = $form->all();
    foreach ($formFields as $key => $field) {
        if ($field->getErrorsAsString()) {
            $errors = $field->getErrors();
            foreach ($errors as $error) {
                $messages[$key][] = $error->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
    var_dump($messages);
```

**EDIT**: Now errors retrieval looks like this (thanks to alex.dominte):

```
public static function getFormErrorMessages(\Symfony\Component\Form\Form $form)
{
    $messages = array();

    foreach ($form->getErrors() as $i => $error) {
        $messages[$i] = $error->getMessage();
    }

    foreach ($form->all() as $child) {
        if (!$child->isValid()) {
            $messages[$child->getName()] = self::getFormErrorMessages($child);
        }
    }

    return $messages;
}
```

Modifications suggested by Pedro Cordeiro make it possible to drop recursion but also make field names unavailable.

Comment: Can you post your controller code? Did you forget to call `$form->isValid()`?

Comment: You need a {{ form_error(regForm.password.first) }}

Comment: Added some controller code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not enough recursion

```
foreach ($formFields as $key => $field) {
    if ($field->getErrorsAsString()) {
        $errors = $field->getErrors();
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
            $messages[$key][] = $error->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Try this - should work for all nested errors:

```
class FormHelper
{
    public static function getErrorMessages($form)
    {
        $errors = array();
        if (!$form->isBound()) return $errors;
        foreach ($form->getErrors() as $key => $error) {
            $template = $error->getMessageTemplate();
            $parameters = $error->getMessageParameters();

            foreach ($parameters as $var => $value) {
                $template = str_replace($var, $value, $template);
            }

            $errors[$key] = $template;
        }
        if ($form->hasChildren()) {
            foreach ($form->getChildren() as $child) {
                if (!$child->isValid()) {
                    $name = $child->getConfig()->getOption('title', $child->getName());
                    $errors[$name] = self::getErrorMessages($child);
                }
            }
        }

        return $errors;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Two things missing from your definitions:

- 1) `error_bubbling` must be manually set to `TRUE` on your fields, so they can throw errors in the ->getErrors() function.
- 2) `cascade_validation` is `FALSE` by default, you must add it too to your parent forms `($builder->add('propertyName', new YourFormNameType(), array('cascade_validation ' => true));`) - [See this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#cascade-validation)

Comment: I give you credit even it's been such a long time... But the same thing have just happened to me, in symfony 5 and your first proposed solution was the key... "error_bubbling". Thanks from the future!

Answer (score 0):

you do not show error message

```
{{ form_errors(regForm.password.first) }}
{{ form_errors(regForm.password.second) }}
```